# Covert a numbers list (pulled from excel) first into integer then string

Tags: string, list, integer

How to covert each number in excel into integer and then string in one go.

Here is the variable token which pulls numbers from excel. When I print it, it shows .0 at the end of the number. I want to first covert then numbers into integer then string. Please help.

token = livefeed.range('d2').expand("down").value

for example to covert one cell into integer then string the forumla used is

token = (str(int(livefeed.range('d2').value))

I have tried token = str(int(livefeed.range('d2').expand("down").value)), but could not resolve it.

Comment: What gets returned in from the statement `token = livefeed.range('d2').expand("down").value`. Is it a single value, a list, a set or what?